# BufferedImage TYPE_INT_RGB incompatible with Mat?

Tags: java, opencv

I have a program that I am trying to capture video and I can get it working. I got the program to work but not the way I wanted it to, I wanted an RGB filter instead of a BRG filter.

```
byte [] dat;
if (dat == null || dat.length != w * h * 3)
        dat = new byte [w * h * 3];
    if (img == null || img.getWidth() != w || img.getHeight() != h || img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
        img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
```

The camera loads but I want an `RGB` filter. This is what I tried to to get my RGB filter so I changed my code to this.

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Mat2Image {
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    BufferedImage img;
    int[] dat;

    Mat2Image(){
    }

    public Mat2Image(Mat mat) {
        getSpace(mat);
    }

    public void getSpace(Mat mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
        int w = mat.cols(), h = mat.rows();
        if (dat == null || dat.length != w * h)
            dat = new int[w * h];
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != w || img.getHeight() != h || img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
            img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    BufferedImage getImage(Mat mat) {
        getSpace(mat);
        mat.get(0, 0, dat);
        img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat.cols(), mat.rows(), dat);
        return img;
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
}
```

When I run the program it throws the exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 16
at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:1045)
at Mat2Image.getImage(Mat2Image.java:44)
at VideoCap.getOneFrame(VideoCap.java:33)
at MyFrame.paint(MyFrame.java:39)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I don't know what this means or what is causing it.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I will add it to the post @mcarlin

Comment: " I got the program to work": the you are all set!

Comment: No I got the camera view to work but it was not the filter I wanted I want RGB not BRG.... @gpasch

Comment: I updated the question and added the stackTrace @mcarlin

Comment: @cuber What rev of opencv are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest 3.2.0 @mcarlin

Answer (score 0):

That stack trace is telling you that the type of the `Mat` object you instantiated doesn't support a get() call with an int[] as the data type. If you take a peek at [the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/misc/java/src/java/core+Mat.java) on line 1034, that's the method that you're calling. It expects your `Mat` object's type field to be `CvType.CV_32S`. I'm not that familiar with OpenCV but you might try instantiating the `Mat` object with the `CvType.CV_32S` as the type parameter in the constructor and see if that solves your issue.